# SQl join a table on integer and json array for integers

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, join

I have two tables with matching column, both of integer types.
Let if i want to store multiple id's in second table. the best way i know is json.

Now problem is how to match a integer from one table and json from another table.

example

Tables
Countries and another is tours

countries column = id, name (integer)
Tours column = id,countries_ids (json), name

I want a join on the basis column countries.id = tours.countries_ids

Comment: Storing JSON formatted values in a database is a terrible idea. You should remove the JSON?

Comment: `store multiple id's in second table. the best way i know is json.`? That is your problem. Don't store multiple id's in 1 row as json. Each id should be in a separate row. Then it is very simple to join the 2 tables.

Comment: sorry, i am thinking about the same , just few minutes ago and u confirmed it o right time " sean "

Answer (score 1):

if you want you can store coma separate id 
and in where condition you can use FIND_IN_SET

Select * from table where FIND_IN_SET (int_id, coma_separate_col)

Comment: This is also a good solution at that time, project is already on the way, so making anther table is bit time consuming, thanks dilip

Answer (score 0):

You can use Primary Key and Foreign Key concept to store multiple ids in second table.